# I can't seem to break out of A $.each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I can't seem to manage to break out of my each loop if the ajax returns an error. I've tried

```
return false;
```

and other similar thing but the $.each still continues to run.

I need to be able to do this so that I can display error messages from my back end after posting it via ajax(I know this is bad practice however a client needed to be able to be able to send multiple forms off at once.).

Can anyone explain what I've done wrong?

```
var postAll = function(button_clicked)
{
 e.preventDefault();

 var form_response = [];
 var formsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("form");

 $.each(formsCollection, function (key, value)
 {
   console.log(value.action);
   console.log(value.id);

   var url = value.action;
   var id = value.id;
   var data = ($('#' + id + '').serialize());


   if (id == 'additionalInfo')
   {
      data = {'Add_info': $('#Add_info').val(),};
   }

    if (id != 'DONE')
   {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function (xhr)
       {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN',$("#token").attr('content'));
        },
        data: data,
        success: function (data)
       {
          console.log('success'); // show response from the php script.
          form_response.push(data); // show response from the php script.
        },
        error: function (data)
        {
          console.log('fail'); // show response from the php script.
          display_errors(data, id); // show response from the php script.
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Exactly what isn't working like it should?

Comment: Do you mean you want to exit the `each` iteration early if any of the requests fails? They are currently executed asynchronously so they may all be sent before the first one returns

Comment: @PeterMader I had it in a for loop but found that each worked a bit better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous, when executing your $.each function it will execute the AJAX call and "Not wait" for the others to finish

To solve your problem you'll have to write a function that will execute the first ajax call and in the success it will execute itself again with the second ajax call.

Example:

```
var data = [form1,form2...etc];
function letsLoop(data,index = 0){
    $.ajax({
        url:....
        success: function(){
            letsLoop(data,index+1);
        },
        error: function(){

        }
    });
}
```

and here you call your function:

```
letsLoop(data,0);
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

If by breaking out of the loop you mean the `return` in your error handler, then it won't work as you think it would.

Your loop creates asynchronous requests 'at once'. Then each of these requests is handled by the browser (more or less simultaneously), then come responses. So by the time your error handler runs the loop has long finished.

BTW, the return in your case relates to the error handler, not the function inside the loop.

So, to achieve what you want you should 'queue' your AJAX requests and perform them one by one.

One possible solution is to create an array of forms then take (and remove it from the array) the first one, perform a request, on a response repeat the whole thing, and keep repeating until the array is empty.